# Does the cross section of $[-1,1]^n$ on a $k$-dimensional subspace always contains a rotated image of $[-1,1]^k$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This question is inspired by [a recent bounty question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/748680/can-a-cube-always-be-fitted-into-the-projection-of-a-cube#765794), but the two questions are different and solving this one, I believe, will *not* lead to an answer of that bounty question.

Suppose $n>k\ge1$ and $V\in M_{k,n}(\mathbb R)$ is the submatrix taken from the first $k$ rows of a real orthogonal matrix of size $n$. Does there always exist a real orthogonal matrix $R$ of size $k$ such that $\|Rv_j\|_1\le1$ for every $j$ (or equivalently, $\|RV\|_1\le1$ where $\|\cdot\|_1$ is the maximum column sum norm)?

Numerical experiments suggest that the answer is negative in general, but affirmative when $k=2$. So, here is my main question: **does the aforementioned $R$ always exist when $k=2$?**

Comment: I don't think that this is always true for $n>2$. At least I was not able to find any such $R$ for the matrix $V=\begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{2} & 0 \\ 0 & \sqrt{6} \end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 & 2\end{bmatrix}$. I got the minimal $\|RV\|_1\approx 1.1154$.

Comment: @PavelJiranek Thank you. Your counterexample is interesting. It appears that both $\operatorname{diag}(-1,1)$ and the rotation by $\pi/6$ are minimisers, but how to prove that the minimal $\|RV\|_1$ for this $V$ is indeed $\frac12+\frac1{\sqrt{6}}$?

Comment: Interesting question. Honestly, I don't know (well, except for $n=2$). The dependence of $\|RV\|_1$ on the angle of rotation can also be quite erratic. The graph of this dependency should actually be the envelope of the graphs for the 1-norms of each of the columns so I guess that the critical points should be their intersections.

Comment: (1.1154 is, of course, the rounded value of $\color{red}{\frac1{\sqrt{2}}}+\frac1{\sqrt{6}}$ and the $\frac12+\frac1{\sqrt{6}}$ in my previous comment is a typo.)

Comment: I should definitely check my calculations again, but it seems to me that the matrix with

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the matrix with rows $$L ( cos(0), cos(t), cos(2t)), \ \  L( sen(0), sen(t), sen(2t)) $$
where $3t=2\pi$ and$ L= 2/\sqrt(3)$ is a counterexample. Infact, taking a rotation of $-s$ radiants yield constraints 
$$ |cos(t_i-s) |+sen(t_i-s) | <= \sqrt(3)/2$$
where $t_i=0,t,2t$. You can add the 3 $t_i$`s given by $t/2,t+t/2, 2t+t/2$ because, for instance, $t/2= 2t+\pi$ and inequalities are invariant for a $\pi$ rotation. You can suppose $ \pi/6<s<\pi/3$ because you have the following simmetries:

1. A rotation by $t/2$;
2. A symmetry which fix the $\pi/6$ diameter.

Because $t_i$ are invariant under these transformations.

On this interval $cos(s), sin(s)$ are positive, and the first derivative of (ineq. $t_i=0$) $f(s)=cos(s) +sin(s) $ is zero only in $\pi/4$. So we should check three values to minimize $f$:

1. $s=\pi/6, \pi/3; f(s) =\sqrt(3)/2 + 1/2 > \sqrt(3)/2$;
2. $s=\pi/4: f(s)=\sqrt(2) > \sqrt(3)/2$

And so there is no $s$ which respect the constraints.

Comment: Noooo I got wrong. It was $L=2/3$ and the same strategy can't work. For n>=4 we have 1/L>=2 and the constraints are easily verified.