# Reduced row echelon form with variables

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

I'm new to this, but if I have the matrix
 \begin{equation} A= \begin{bmatrix}1&2&3&1\\2&1&1&x^2+x \\ 3&6&x&x-6\end{bmatrix}\end{equation}
and if I want to use the reduced row echelon form formula, do I have to get the $x$ variables to $0$, or could they stay in the matrix?

Answer (score 0):

You must be careful when row reducing with unknown parameters in the matrix...you can row reduce, but beware of errors such as division by zero, for example if you multiply the last row by $x^{-1}$ you must be sure that $x \neq 0$, else that row operation is undefined. You get the same problem if you multiply by $(x-6)^{-1}$ (and perhaps it is possible that $x=6$, in which case you have division by zero again), etc.

So my advice in this case: row reduce normally until you have row echelon form (without dividing by any factors containing $x$). You won't be able to go all the way to RRE.

Comment: I don't understand this advice. Use the pivot in the first row to clear out the first column. When you do that, the bottom row will become $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & x-9 & x-9 \end{bmatrix}$, and so we will have rank $2$ if $x=9$, rank $3$ otherwise.

Comment: @TedShifrin sure, but you still don't have RRE. maybe yes, my advice to exchange the rows is not best, I didn't check to see that such is a simple reduction is possible in the first step...BUT THE POINT IS you can row reduce, but avoid division by terms containing $x$. Capisce?

Comment: Switching rows to get rid of the $1$ pivot *and* introduce an $x$ in the first row is *not* going to help anything. Let's see your RRE that way. I don't need the "capisce?" from you: I've written a few linear algebra texts :D

Comment: @TedShifrin haha! ok grandmaster, sorry it was bad advice...i removed it, but at least you maybe agree that it was not really the main point of my answer?

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry, this might not be the right place to ask, but I'd really appreciate if you could have a look at this q, maybe you have a way to prove it?: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/748680/can-a-cube-always-be-fitted-into-the-projection-of-a-cube

Comment: Very cool question. I will try to look carefully when I emerge from final exams.